# C++/SDL 'void*' is not a point-to-object type

Tags: c++, object, pointers, sdl, void

I'm new on C++ and I'm trying to make some testing with C++ and SDL and in SDL we have a function:

```
SDL_TimerID SDL_AddTimer(Uint32 interval, SDL_NewTimerCallback callback, void *param);
```

which I can pass a callback for the timer created.
But apparently it converts my instance this to *void so I can't retrieve it again on the update method which is static, and it's interesting but the the SDL_AddTime doesn't work on a non static callback function.

Well, so my problem is that when trying to call the public method render through the void* param argument It complains about not being a pointer-to-object-type...

Is there any way I can get the Character instance again inside the update method since I don't have control over the SDL_AddTime function and I have to pass the required parameters?

Thanks

```
#include "Character.h"

Character::Character(void)
{
  timer = SDL_AddTimer(33, update, this);
  this->render(); // is called without problem
}

//static method
Uint32 Character::update(Uint32 interval,void* param)
{
  param->render(); // yields: 'void*' is not a pointer-to-object type;

  SDL_Event event;

  event.type = SDL_USEREVENT;
  event.user.code = 1020;
  event.user.data1 = param;

  SDL_PushEvent(&event);

  return interval;
}

void Character::render(void)
{
  printf("rendering character \n");
}
```

Comment: The reason for this is easily made apparent. Type's define what operations you can perform on data. `void*` indicates a pointer to an unknown type. What operations can we perform on an unknown type?

Comment: Hi GMan, so you're saying that the principle for this *void parameter is to not be used, could you please help me saying if this approach would be correct or maybe use another way? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: FWIW, you can't use a pointer to non-static method because those have a different type in C++, and your API (the SDL_AddTimer function) isn't expecting that type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a reinterpret_cast - a static_cast should be OK:

```
Character * cp = static_cast <Character *>( param );
```

You should avoid reinterpret_cast - it is almost always implementation specific, and may hide problems - just like old-style C casts.

Comment: But isn't `static_cast` made with no type checks or anything, making it just like the C-style casts?

Comment: No, it isn't - the rules are a bit complicated, but it does what STATIC (i.e. compile-time) checking it can. Otherwise, it would be identical with reinterpret_cast.

Comment: Ironically, Lira, that's what `reinterpret_cast` does. `reinterpret_cast` says "treat X as Y" and the compiler goes "Ok!". `static_cast` says "Treat X as Y, but make sure this conversion is defined and use that method." and the compiler either goes "Ok, I see how" or "Nope.". For pointers, you can implicitly cast from `T*` to `void*`, and `static_cast` the other way.

Comment: This is one of the situation where I would absolutely use reinterpret_cast<>(). The static_cast<>() does not give you any more safety (because all the checks are compile time) and by using reinterpret_cast<>() you are explicitly documenting that you are doing something that is dangerous.

Comment: Martin: Though for null pointers that have different (non-zero) representations for different types (not that I know of any such real systems myself.. but I believe it's allowed by the standard), won't reinterpret\_cast do the *wrong* thing and static\_cast work correctly?

Comment: I believe the standard does guarantee that NULL pointers are 0: N2521=08-0031: 18.1.3: The macro NULL is an implementation-defined C++ null pointer constant. 4.10.1: A null pointer constant is an integral constant expression rvalue of integer type that evaluates to zero.

Comment: GMan: Thanks for the explanation, learned something new today :)

Comment: @Martin Let's not start that one again. You are confusing the zero used in the code with the internal rep of the null pointer.

Answer (score 2):

Cast your param pointer to a Character:

```
Character * charPtr = reinterpret_cast<Character *>(param);
charPtr->render();
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason is that C++ is a strong typed language. To change one type to another, you need to cast it first:

```
Uint32 Character::update(Uint32 interval, void* param)
{
    reinterpret_cast<Character* >(param)->render();

    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, if you were to call a lot of stuff in a function, to save all the nasty reinterpret_cast stuff everywhere you can do

`Character * myCharacter = reinterpret_cast<Character* >(param);`

Which then lets you do 'myCharacter->render();' or whathaveyou...